# mlr3 optimized average of ensemble

Tags: r, mlr3, superlearner

I try to optimize the averaged prediction of two logistic regressions in a classification task using a superlearner.

My measure of interest is `classif.auc`

The `mlr3` help file tells me (`?mlr_learners_avg`)

> Predictions are averaged using weights (in order of appearance in the
> data) which are optimized using nonlinear optimization from the
> package "nloptr" for a measure provided in measure (**defaults to
> classif.acc** for LearnerClassifAvg and regr.mse for LearnerRegrAvg).
> Learned weights can be obtained from $model. Using non-linear
> optimization is implemented in the SuperLearner R package. For a more
> detailed analysis the reader is referred to LeDell (2015).

I have two questions regarding this information:

1. When I look at the [source code](https://github.com/cran/mlr3pipelines/blob/master/R/LearnerAvg.R) I think `LearnerClassifAvg$new()` defaults to `"classif.ce"`, is that true?
   I think I could set it to `classif.auc` with `param_set$values <- list(measure="classif.auc",optimizer="nloptr",log_level="warn")`
2. The help file refers to the `SuperLearner` package and [LeDell 2015](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/3kb142r2). As I understand it correctly, the proposed "AUC-Maximizing Ensembles through Metalearning" solution from the paper above is, however, not impelemented in `mlr3`? Or do I miss something? Could this solution be applied in `mlr3`? In the `mlr3` book I found a paragraph regarding [calling an external optimization function](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/extending-tuners.html#calling-an-external-optimization-function), would that be possible for `SuperLearner`?

Comment: > "defaults to "classif.ce", is that true?"

Yes, and strictly speaking the documentation needs to be fixed here, although optimizing `classif.acc` and `classif.ce` are functionally equivalent (the one maximizing the accuracy, the other minimizing the misclassification error).

Comment: Thank you for clarification. As far as I understand it correctly `LearnerClassifAvg` calls the NLOPT_LN_COBYLA algorthm from Nloptr.  Are you planning to implement an AUC maximizing metalearner (as the cited ref proposes)?

Comment: Hi! Trying something similar. Worked? If so, do you mind to share a code snipped of what you did? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, **LeDell2015** proposes and evaluate a general strategy that optimizes AUC as a black-box function by learning optimal weights. They do not really propose a **best** strategy or any concrete defaults so I looked into the defaults of the **SuperLearner** package's AUC optimization strategy.

Assuming I understood the paper correctly:

The `LearnerClassifAvg` basically implements what is proposed in **LeDell2015** namely, it optimizes the weights for **any** metric using non-linear optimization. **LeDell2015**  focus on the special case of optimizing AUC. As you rightly pointed out, by setting the measure to `"classif.auc"` you get a meta-learner that optimizes AUC. The default with respect to which optimization routine is used deviates between **mlr3pipelines** and the **SuperLearner** package, where we use `NLOPT_LN_COBYLA` and **SuperLearner** *...  uses the Nelder-Mead method via the `optim` function to minimize rank loss* ([from the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SuperLearner/versions/2.0-26/topics/SuperLearner)).

So in order to get exactly the same behaviour, you would need to implement a `Nelder-Mead` `bbotk::Optimizer` [similar to here](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/extending-tuners.html#calling-an-external-optimization-function) that simply wraps `stats::optim` with method `Nelder-Mead` and carefully compare settings and stopping criteria. I am fairly confident that `NLOPT_LN_COBYLA` delivers somewhat comparable results, [**LeDell2015**](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/3kb142r2) has a comparison of the different optimizers for further reference.

Thanks for spotting the error in the documentation. I agree, that the description is a little unclear and I will try to improve this!